'update lines' function in 3d animation
I am trying to animate in 3D an arm represented by 2 segments (3 points A, B and C of which I have 3D coordinates in a numpy array (shape (n,3))). Only the arm at instant t (between 0 and n) should be visible, all 'previous' arms must be erased !
The only piece I am stuck with is the 'update lines' function, this being the rest of my code :
walks = [A, B, C]
num_steps = max([i.shape[0] for i in walks])

# Attaching 3D axis to the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")

# Create lines initially without data
lines = [ax.plot([], [], [])[0] for _ in range(len(walks)-1)]

''' # Setting the Axes properties
ax.set(xlim3d=(min([np.nanmin(i[:,0]) for i in walks]), max([np.nanmax(i[:,0]) for i in walks])), xlabel='X')
ax.set(ylim3d=(min([np.nanmin(i[:,1]) for i in walks]), max([np.nanmax(i[:,1]) for i in walks])), ylabel='Y')
ax.set(zlim3d=(min([np.nanmin(i[:,2]) for i in walks]), max([np.nanmax(i[:,2]) for i in walks])), zlabel='Z')''' 

# Creating the Animation object
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, update_lines, num_steps, fargs=(walks, lines), interval=100)

plt.show()

Any help is welcome, I need to hand it in shortly !!
The answer seems to be in this article : Updating line in 3D plot Animation but I can't manage to adapt its script to mine.

What about writing the update_lines function are you stuck on?

@jared sorry I was off ! I am stuck on the .set_data that most of these functions (in other codes) use : I don't understand what it does ! Thanks for replying so quickly though !!

Well, you don't seem to have any updates_line function right now. But .set_data should be given all the data you want plotted in that frame of the animation (not just the new data to be added).

Alright ! Thanks, a lot clearer now ! Couldn't find such a simple answer anywhere else ;-)
